# Conditional variational autoencoder understanding

Tags: keras

I'm having trouble understanding an implementation in Keras of conditional variational autoencoders. The associated jupyter notebook is [here](https://github.com/nnormandin/Conditional_VAE/blob/master/Conditional_VAE.ipynb).

My issue is, I don't see how you would pass the test set through the model. I know you need to use the recognition network for training and the prior network for testing. I think that means you're supposed to concatenate the result of the prior network and some function of the input, but I only see an encoder (which takes in both x and y) and a decoder. Where in this implementation is the prior network (just x)?

Comment: I fear you are basically misunderstanding variational autoencoders. A VAE is similar to a normal autoencoder, with the difference that you try to compute the relevant statistics of the encoding distribution Q(z|X) by sampling at training time. There is no "recognition" going on, and also the notion of "prior" network makes no sense.

Comment: Hi @AndreaAsperti, I'm talking about a conditional VAE, not a straight-up VAE. A CVAE does have a recognition network and a prior network. See here, for example: "When training CVAE, a recognition network...is learned to sample z for deriving the generative network....On the other hand, the prediction stage of CVAE requires a (different) prior network...for producing z." (https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02295)